# Matrix to column excel vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix of usernames running along the top and application names(wraps) running down the side. We have put an X in each cell where a particular person uses an application but we now need to make a standard table of 2 columns: Username & App Name and then list the users and the associated application used.

Matrix looks like:

```
Username| jsmith| bspence| tjones 
 Wrap ID|
     abc|           X        X
     def|   X       O
     ghi|   X       X
```

I need to change to the format:

```
Username|WrapID | value
Jsmith | abc     | X
Jsmith | ghi     | X
bspence | def    | O
bspence | ghi    | X
tjones | abc     | X
```

I have tried joining every formula I can think of, if(index(match) among others and am at a complete loss. I dont know any VB but it looks like this is the only solution to the problem.

Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

I made a code like this, but this give me errors.

```
Sub ConvertMatrix() 
Dim lngX As Long, vIn, vUser, vOut 
Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngIn As Range, k As Long 
Set rngIn = [a1].CurrentRegion 
vIn = rngIn.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngIn.Rows.Count - 1).Value 
vUser = rngIn.Resize(, rngIn.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).Rows(1).Value 
lngX = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngIn, "X") 
Redim vOut(1 To lngX, 1 To 3) 
For i = 1 To UBound(vUser, 2) 
    For j = 1 To UBound(vIn, 1) 
        If vIn(j, i + 1) = "X" Then 
            k = k + 1 
            vOut(k, 1) = vUser(1, i) 
            vOut(k, 2) = vIn(j, 1) 
            vOut(k, 3) = vIn(j, i + 1)
        End If 
    Next 
Next 
With Worksheets.Add 
    .Range("A1:B1") = Array("User", "WrapID", "value") 
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), 3).Value = vOut 
End With
```

End Sub

Many Thnaks

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ConvertMatrix()

    Dim arrMatrix As Variant
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        arrMatrix = .Value
        If Not IsArray(arrMatrix) Then Exit Sub 'No data
        ReDim arrResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)), 1 To 3)
    End With

    For cIndex = 2 To UBound(arrMatrix, 2)
        For rIndex = 3 To UBound(arrMatrix, 1)
            If Len(arrMatrix(rIndex, cIndex)) > 0 Then
                ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrMatrix(1, cIndex)
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = arrMatrix(rIndex, 1)
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 3) = arrMatrix(rIndex, cIndex)
            End If
        Next rIndex
    Next cIndex

    If ResultIndex > 0 Then
        With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            With .Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(arrResults, 2))
                .Value = Array("Username", "WrapID", "Value")
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
            .Range("A2").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults
            .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If

    Erase arrMatrix
    Erase arrResults

End Sub
```

Comment: out of interest wouldn't VBA garbage collector (hmm, actually, does it even have one?!) come along and clean up the arrays shortly after they go out of scope? I don't erase my arrays unless I am still in the middle of a procedure but know I won't need them again. You got me thinking that maybe I should, however!

Comment: I'm pretty sure local variables get garbage collected automatically, so it is probably both redundant and wasteful for me to try to manually garbage collect. It's an old habit that hasn't really died.  Though depending on who you ask, not releasing variables can (in rare cases) cause Excel to not quit properly.  So really, it's not necessary, but it's a habit of mine.

Comment: For more info, see [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/74789-Set-Variable-to-Nothing-%28VBA-for-Excel%29)

Comment: Just googled a bit around it (mainly seems to be from old VB6 discussions). I see a bit of a divided camp between yes - it could cause issues otherwise and no - it could cause issues if you do! In the absence of the habit, I think I will just keep going in ignorance / not bother (lazy .NET fellow that I am). Thanks for the info.